# iPad VNC client: Edovia Screens: Does it support multiple displays?

Tags: ipad, display, remote-desktop

Does Edovia "Screens" support multiple displays?  My Mac has two displays, and I need to be able access applications that open on either one of them.

Comment: Not an answer since I haven't used the app itself, but am speaking from general VNC experience. Generally, with VNC, the VNC server exposes a wide canvas that encompasses both screens in whichever orientation they're arranged in. It doesn't take any special trick to switch between displays, you just roll over (or drag the window scrollbar) in the direction you would normally.

Comment: I appreciate your input.  At the moment I am using iTeleport, and the second display does not appear, though I recall that it did when I first started using iTeleport.  Perhaps there is a configuration trick.

Comment: I suspect iTeleport is not VNC, most other products are. Therein lies the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Screens does let you select a specific display on the fly when you connect to Mac. This is a feature built in Screen Sharing, which is Apple's VNC protocol.

If you're connecting to a PC, you can use ports 5901...590x to specific the display to use before connecting.

Answer (score 1):

In short: Screens supports multiple monitors but they'll appear as one wide display.